# skipping running for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

```
static int bookNum;
```

I did do some stuff to bookNum in other code prior to this one so it has a value and I already defined it at the beginning.

```
public static void processtrans()throws FileNotFoundException{

  Scanner input = new Scanner(transFile);
  String line = input.nextLine();

  double dollar = 0;
  int transNum = 1;

  while (input.hasNextLine()) {
     int Space = line.indexOf (" ");
     int Space2 = line.indexOf (" ", Space + 1);
     String action = line.substring(0,Space);

     if (action == "ORDER"){
        int Space3 = line.indexOf (" ", Space2 + 1);
        String isbn = line.substring(Space + 1, Space2);
        int num = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(Space2 + 1, Space3));
        int custNum = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(Space3 + 1));

        for (int x = 0; x < bookNum; x++){
           if (bookarray[x][0] == isbn){
              int stock = Integer.parseInt(bookarray[x][2]);
              if (stock >= num){
                 stock -= num;
                 bookarray[x][2] = Integer.toString(stock);
                 System.out.println("Order filled");
              }      
           }
        }
     }
     line = input.nextLine();
  }
}
```

This code compiled but didn't print anything so I started debugging it and realized that the program doesn't execute `for` loop, it jumps from:

```
 int custNum = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(Space3 + 1));
```

to:

```
 line = input.nextLine();
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: You didnt declare bookNum!

Comment: you have not declared bookNum, may be you want to use custNum instead of bookNum

Comment: you can not declare a static variable inside a method...it will show illegal start of expression

Comment: Where is bookNum declared?? If it is declared at class level are you initializing any where,if not it will take default value 0

Comment: Never do == on objects!

Answer (score 1):

`bookNum` is not initialized, so its value is 0

Comment: I did things with bookNum before that it has a value

Comment: Put a breakpoint in line `for (int x = 0; x < bookNum; x++){` and check `bookNum` value, please. Maybe your `processtrans()` method is executed before `bookNum` update